# Sesqulinear forms and weak convergence

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, weak-convergence, sesquilinear-forms

Let $a[x,y]$ be a densely defined, symmetric sequilinear form with domain $D(a)$ on a complex Hilbert space.  Suppose that $x, y \in D(a)$ and there is a sequence $x_n \in D(a)$ such that $x_n$ weakly converges to $x$.  Is it true that $a[x_n,y]$ converges to $a[x,y]$?

This is certainly true if $a[x,y]$ is the form associated with a symmetric operator $A$ by $a[x,y] = \langle Ax,y \rangle$ when $D(a) = D(A)$, but what about for other symmetric forms?

Comment: If the form $a[x,y]$ has the property described above, then it also has the following property: for every $y \in D(a)$, the linear functional $x \mapsto a[x,y]$ is bounded on $D(a)$, and hence on the whole Hilbert space.  Otherwise, there would be a sequence $x_n \in D(a)$ such that $\|x_n\|=1$ and $|a[x_n,y]| \rightarrow \infty$, but then the sequence $\hat{x}_n = x_n/|a[x_n,y]|$ would converge to zero even though $a[\hat{x}_n,y]$ does not converge to $a[0,y]$.

This seems like it would be a surprising property for all sesquilinear forms to have, but I don't have a counterexample.